# Spring Aspect or AspectJ Pointcut that matches the value of annotation

Tags: java, spring, aop, aspectj, spring-aop

Code:

```
@Controller
public class TestController {

    @RequestMapping("/{abc}/{def}")
    public String handleTest(HttpServletRequest request,
                             HttpServletResponse response,
                             @PathVariable("abc") String abc,
                             @PathVariable("def") String def) {
        return abc;
    }
}
```

I want to write a Pointcut that matches the `@PathVariable("abc")`. However, the best I can do at the moment is to match a method that has `@PathVariable` somewhere, then use code logic to find out if there's a value `abc`

```
@Pointcut("execution(public * *(.., @org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable (*), ..))")
```

I can't see if there's a technical difficulty of achieving this task, since `abc` is available during compile-time.

Is there a way to specify the `abc` in the Pointcut?

Comment: To clarify, you want to match all methods that contain one ore more parameters that are annotated with `@PathVariable`?

Comment: I want to match all methods that contains `@PathVariable("abc")`. i.e. contains an argument that is annotated with `@PathVariable` and in that annotation there's a `value="abc"`

Comment: and I want to get it done in Pointcut. I know how to do it using `JoinPoint.getSignature()` in code, but that process is tedious and I'm not a big fan.

Comment: I agree that there shouldn't be any technical difficulty, but Spring doesn't [support it](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-pointcuts-designators). The signature solution seems most appropriate.

Comment: AspectJ does support annotation value matching but not for parameter annotations yet. For example this is valid AJ syntax: `execution(* *(@Foo("abc") *))` - a method whose parameter type is annotated with @Foo and the string value in the annotation is "abc". But if you attempt the same for parameter annotations right now you will get (at least when using ajc to compile it) a compiler message indicating it isn't supported yet.

Comment: Addendum to what Andy just said: Another restriction applies to annotation parameter matching in AspectJ: You can match an exact value, but not a substring or regex pattern, AFAIK. At least this is what I remember when I used it a while ago. So if e.g. you want to match on the "abc" substring in the `@RequestMapping`, you currently cannot do it.